# Pandas read_csv giving file does not exist error on windows

Tags: python, pandas

I upgraded my jupyter notebook (using Anaconda) to python 3 (I uninstalled the old version and reinstalled anaconda for py3). A simple pd.read_csv that was working before is now giving `File Does not exist error.`
I am on windows 7.

```
filepath="C:\\python\\cfg\\TEST.csv"
cfgfile=pd.read_csv(filepath)
```

Also tried:

```
filepath="C:/python/cfg/TEST.csv"
```

What did i do wrong?

Comment: Please see EDIT. I did typo.

Answer (score 0):

How about that with **filepath**?

```
import os
import pandas as pd

filepath="C:/python/cfg/TEST.csv"
os.chdir(os.path.dirname(filepath))
cfgfile= pd.read_csv(os.path.basename(filepath))
```

Comment: Please see EDIT. My typo

Comment: @Victor see my EDIT now

Comment: I get : The system cannot find the path specified. This was working fine in python2.7

Comment: see this link https://medium.com/@ageitgey/python-3-quick-tip-the-easy-way-to-deal-with-file-paths-on-windows-mac-and-linux-11a072b58d5f and try with `pathlib`